# Selenium WebDriver Exception

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium WebDriver to automate my testcases, and I am getting:

```
  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
    Build info: version: '2.30.0', revision: 'dc1ef9c', time: '2013-02-19 00:15:27'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    Command duration or timeout: 47.94 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 15:53:30'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

An Exception by controlling browser instances, can it will be solved? How can you control browser instances to 1 or 2?

Comment: See this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webdriver/600j__wM0qY) regarding the same issue.

Comment: Whats the browser version?

Comment: Latest firefox version does not work for me. I would say FF v17 would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try below things

```
By killing all firefox instances (Go to task manager and kill all firefox processes.)
or
By uninstall & install firefox.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can resolve it by upgrade your Selenium Jar and Firefox browser version to the latest one.

docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ -Selenium  JAR

www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/ -Firefox

Comment: Footers linking to your company are not allowed. Please tell your coworkers to stop doing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, when you upgrade the old version of Firefox or when the Firefox browser gets upgraded. By this, the Webdriver binding port is not matching with the Firefox.

1. Just uninstall the firefox and install the firefox again.
2. Download the latest Selenium Webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Selenium server to latest one . 
Latest Firefox version brings up these kind of issues .
Downgrade your firefox version.